# Is it possible to create a text file and show result in it instead of showing result in web browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, file, asp.net-web-api

Lets say I have an ASP.NET Web API which displays data result on the web browser, eg. `{"Result": 10}` when I run the application.

Is it possible for the result to be shown in a text file when I run the application?

Meaning when I run the application, a text file is created with the data `{"Result": 10}` in it. Or, the data is shown in the web browser and also a text file is created with the same data in it. Is that possible?

Comment: Which ASP.NET framework and version are you using? What have you tried? Where do you want the text file to be created?

Comment: I looked through the question that i have been said to have duplicated before i posted this question. If i'm not wrong, is that generating a file that already exist?

Comment: Do you really need to create a local file? You can return the string directly to the browser without first saving it. Or you could avoid generating the string in the first place - this is a Json string. You can use `return Ok(myResult)` and have Web API serialize it, or `return Json(myResult);` to return it as Json explicitly.

Comment: If you really want to return a file, the duplicate is the correct answer. *You* will have to write the code that saves your string in a file first, although that's trivial `File.WriteAllText(somePath,myString)`. If you don't need that file though, use `OK()` or `Json()`

Comment: I want the text file to be created under desktop. So far i have done up to showing the output in web browser. Now i'm thinking if i can show the data that is shown in the web browser, in a text file too, as per the request of my supervisor

Comment: You cannot put files on a web site visitor's desktop. You can only offer files for download, the user has to decide where to save them.

Comment: Ok that is true. If i follow the duplicate will i be able to get that? Or will i have to add somemore methods?

Answer (score 2):

Try to generate the response like this

```
HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage()
{
    Content = new StringContent(
                responseData,
                Encoding.UTF8,
                "text/plain"
            )
};
```

it will add header Content-type = text/plain in the response. This might help you.

Comment: Ok ill try thanks.

Comment: if you can add some working code sample or fiddle that would be great

Comment: This does not create a file anywhere.